# Tomcat Configuration Editor or Tool

Tags: java

The tomcat configuration is been manually edited always prone to human errors always. This causes delays during deployment or production. This is a big problem.

Is there is any tool available to configure via wizard which saves the XML accordingly

```
Ex:

1. Change the ports
2. Configure two applications in tomcat
3. Servlet and Context paths
4. Even the JVM options are manual which is also error prone
```

Basically a configuration wizard for tomcat

Thanks.